# Click event not firing for custom UserControl on a form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, eventhandler

I have created a UserControl called `Toggle`, this is my code for it

```
[DefaultEvent("Click")]
public partial class Toggle : UserControl {

    public bool ToggleStatus { get { return toggleStatus; } }
    private bool toggleStatus { get; set; }

    public Toggle() {
        InitializeComponent();
        toggleStatus = true;
    }

    private void toggleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (toggleStatus) { // currently set as "true" or "on"
            this.lblSwitch.Dock = DockStyle.Right;                
            this.pnlBackground.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            toggleStatus = false;
        } else { // currently set as "false" or "off"
            this.lblSwitch.Dock = DockStyle.Left;                
            this.pnlBackground.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            toggleStatus = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The `toggleClick` method is tied to the click event of controls within the `UserControl`; this fires off just fine.

However, when I put my `Toggle` control on a form and attempt to tie an event to the click of it, it won't fire off.

```
    private void toggleSoundClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        soundToggle = !soundToggle;
    }
```

I've made sure that the proper method is tied to the click event in my Designer.cs file of both my UserControl and my form

UserControl:

```
this.lblSwitch.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toggleClick);
this.pnlBackground.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toggleClick);
```

(I have it tied to two controls on my `Toggle` since I want it to fire no matter where you click on the control)

Form:

```
this.tglSound.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toggleSoundClick);
```

The expected behavior for the UserControl is to fire off `toggleClick` (which it does) then the form should fire off `toggleSoundClick` (which it doesn't). I have seen this behavior work fine for other UserControls I have designed and used in this same project.

**To clarify:**

I have a UserControl called `ServerDisplay`. I have a method tied to the click event of the background panel of `ServerDisplay` (in the code for ServerDisplay) that shows a random MessageBox:

```
    private void ServerDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
```

Then, I have a `ServerDisplay` control contained within my form. I have a method tied to the click event of it as well (in the code for my form)

```
    private void serverDisplayClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (loaded) {
            ServerDisplay display = (ServerDisplay)sender;
            this.lblLastServer.Text = "Last server joined was " + display.Server.Name + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt");
            centerControl(this.lblLastServer);
        }
    }
```

When I click on the `ServerDisplay` control in my form, it shows the MessageBox (code from within `ServerDisplay`), then updates the label I specified in the code (code from form). This is the intended behavior, but it is not working for my other `UserControl`.

Comment: How are you wiring up the events?  In code or in the designer?

Comment: In the designer (in both the Event settings [lightning icon in properties pane] and by double checking the Designer.cs

Comment: Please post the line in the designer that actually subscribes your event to your `toggleSoundClick`. It's not uncommon to accidentally subscribe to the wrong control or even the form when doing it from the designer.

Comment: Edited, it's above `To clarify`

Comment: You showed the `toggleSeedClick` which isn't your `toggleSoundClick`.

Comment: Ah sorry, I have multiple controls of `Toggle` that are all having this issue, I've updated it.

Comment: And can you show the line of code that registers the Toggle's toggleClick method with its own Click event?

Comment: Certainly, I've edited my answer.

Comment: I thought maybe doing away with the `Toggle` control completely, then remaking it might fix it, no such luck still the same thing happening.

Comment: I've posted an answer, I finally figured it out but it opens up another question for me that I'll have to ask separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! The way I had the control set up, I had the control itself, a panel filling up the entire background (I used this for the color), and then another panel inside the first panel to act as the "switch".

When I got rid of the first panel and just used the background of the control for the color and a small panel for the switch, it works when I click the background, but not when I click the "switch" panel. I guess this opens up more questions that I'll have to ask separately from this one, but at least I got my answer.